# Tamanhos de Fontes, Botões e Formatação CSS maior

Tags: debate, status-pronto, design

Aqui no Stack Overflow em Português, nota-se visivelmente que o tamanho das fontes, realces e tamanho de botões é visivelmente menor que no site gringo.

As partes que mais notei diferença:

- Texto marcado como código (como se fosse o conjunto de tags `<pre><code>`) é pequeno a ponto de ser cansativo ler códigos grandes (14px do SO contra 12px do SOpt);
- Os títulos na Index são menores (o tamanho é o mesmo, 17px, mas no SO o texto é negritado);
- Há espaço entre os botões que poderia seu usado para aumentá-los e aumentar sua fonte.

Eu sei que parece reclamação de velho cego, mas é notável a diferença de conforto pra ler entre um site e outro.

Há alguma razão para ser assim? Há a possibilidade desse CSS ser normatizado?

Comment: A princípio eu estranhei um pouco, mas para ser bem sincero hoje eu prefiro o visual do SOPT do que o do SOEN. O texto marcado com aspas (blockquote) nosso realça bem mais que o deles que se confunde com o texto marcado como código pois é tudo cinza.

Comment: Sim, mas precisa ser em 12px? Eu não vejo problema algum de subir a fonte normal pra 16px, por exemplo, até porque os monitores hoje em dia são grandes para abarcar fontes desse tamanho.

Comment: Sem querer te chamar de velho cego mas você pode dar zoom na página :p. _Tentando_ responder sua pergunta, acho que não foi ninguém daqui que escolheu, dá uma olhada [aqui](http://meta.pt.stackoverflow.com/q/22/3117) tem um comentário que o Gabe diz que precisa falar com o "pessoal" sobre o layout daqui.

Comment: Eu acho que estão experimentando aqui para quem sabe atualizar o visual do SO no futuro. Eu pessoalmente gosto da nossa versão, acostumei com tudo menor e estou achando o SO meio feio. Mas independentemente do que acontecer, parece que está na hora de você consultar um oftalmologista :)

Answer (score 3):

[Como diz o @Math](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/1188/tamanhos-de-fontes-botoes-e-formatacao-css-maior#comment2691_1188), também acho que nosso `blockquote` é muito melhor. Cada site tem seu layout específico, ser tão igual ao SO em Inglês é tão vantajoso assim?

Normalmente, a resposta no [Meta Stack Exchange](http://meta.stackexchange.com) para esse tipo de sugestão/requisição, que não é *bug* ou *melhoria notável*, é:

### Instale um User Script e personalize como quiser.